# why there is difference in R.squared value taken from regression model and calculated manually

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression

Two sample vector taken and named actual and predictor . i try to calculate
 the R-squared value using formula [ manual way ] and other i pulled the R -squared value from linear regression model , we are seeing significant difference of [ 0.10 ] approximately . could someone help me to understand this OR am i missing something .

```
actual <- c(4, 6, 9, 10, 4, 6, 4, 7, 8, 7)
predicted <- c(5, 6, 8, 10, 4, 8, 4, 9, 8, 9)

df <- data.frame(actual , predicted) 

linear_model <- lm(predicted ~ actual , data = df )
```

linear_model

```
Call:
lm(formula = predicted ~ actual, data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)       actual  
     1.2420       0.9012  

summary(linear_model) 

Call:
lm(formula = predicted ~ actual, data = df)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.3531 -0.7975 -0.3531  1.0512  1.4494 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   1.2420     1.1957   1.039 0.329319    
actual        0.9012     0.1757   5.129 0.000898 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.118 on 8 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7668,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7376 
F-statistic:  26.3 on 1 and 8 DF,  p-value: 0.0008976

error <- predicted  - actual  

rss <- c(crossprod(error))

tss <- c(crossprod(actual - mean(actual)))

1 - (rss / tss)
```

0.654320987654321

```
summary(linear_model)$r.squared
```

0.766784655673544

Comment: R-square is estimated from the residuals, your formula is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

**If your computations and R's are different, suspect yours.**

There is no error, you are mistaking a variable named `predicted` for the predicted values.

You will have to compare the computations done by hand with the value reported in the `summary`.

```
summary(linear_model)$r.squared
#[1] 0.7667847
```

Now, first of all, compute your denominator `TSS` correctly.

```
TSS <- c(crossprod(predicted - mean(predicted)))
```

**First** computation of r-squared, using the model residuals.

```
err1 <- linear_model$residuals
RSS1 <- c(crossprod(err1))
1 - RSS1/TSS
#[1] 0.7667847
```

As you can see, the result is the same as the one given by `summary`.

**Second** way of computing r-squared, compute the fitted values, then the residuals.

```
err2 <- predicted - predict(linear_model)
RSS2 <- c(crossprod(err2))
1 - RSS2/TSS
#[1] 0.7667847
```

Once again there is no error.

Comment: Thank you Rui .i corrected the formula . i got the same R squared value in both cases .